# Angular - Is it possible to make a http call which usually take 10mins from one component and notify the user in another component

Tags: angular

I have a http call in one component which usually take time between 5 - 10 minutes for processing. During this http call I want to make sure that all other router links works as per their normal behaviour. When I switch from this component to another component, all component will listner for  this http call processing, once this http processing is done I want to show one notification to user saying that analysis is complete.

Comment: Technically, yes, this is exactly how HTTP is implemented inside Angular w/ Observables.  The HTTP call is non-blocking meaning people can still use the app.  Practically speaking, I would expect this HTTP call to timeout both on the client and the server, so you'll have deal with that somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the call from a service and let the components that should get informed when it is finished subscribe to an observable of that service.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done different ways depending on your preferred method of showing the notification to the user.

**Option 1** Component driven

Move your execution of your long http call to a service

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  onNotificationRecieved: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  myLongHttpCall() {
    this.http.get('myurl').subscribe(result => {
      this.onNotificationRecieved.next(result);
    }, err => {
      //Handle error
    });
  }
}
```

and have the active component listening to the result

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {

  private _unsubscribe: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this._unsubscribe = new Subject();

    myService.onNotificationRecieved.pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribe)).subscribe(result => {
      //Show notification to user 
    });
  }
   ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Unsubscribe from subscription
        this._unsubscribe.next();
        this._unsubscribe.complete();
    }

}
```

**Option 2** Service Driven (if you are using a toast notification for example) 
Keep all elements within the service meaning you don't have to worry about which ever component is currently being shown

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  }

  myLongHttpCall() {
    this.http.get('myurl').subscribe(result => {
      let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
      this.snackBar.open('Your Notification Message', 'Dismiss', config);
    }, err => {
      //Handle fail
    });
  }
}
```